# JAX-RS JSON object to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, jax-rs

I am new to JAX-RS and trying to build a simple website interface.

So I have written a function returning a JSON object
like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/mypath")
@Produces (Mediatype.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String returnJson() {
    String json = //.... fill String 
    return json;
}
```

which works well when browsing to this path.

On the other hand I have a UI page like this:

```
@GET
Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public InputStream viewUI() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File page = new File("page.html");
    return new FileInputStream(page);
}
```

which works also.

Next thing I want to do is filling a dropdown list in my `page.html` with JavaScript, which also should not be a problem.

But I dont know how to get the JSON object to the JavaScript array (in `page.html`).

Comment: This is a clientside JavaScript problem. You can use a library like jQuery that helps you with making AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,  when using jaxrs, you don't  need to convert objects to json. This is done automatically by jaxrs. Your method should return an object. As you asking to convert json into array, I assume, your method should return a List. Regarding of how to call and consume results from the rest service, as per Luts Horn comment,  you need to use some sort of client side library,  for example jquery.

You can look here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm